# What is the definition of this $L^p$-space?

Tags: real-analysis, definition, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

I am reading a book by E. Zehnder and I am confused about an $L^p$-space he is using. What is the definition of the space

$$ L^p(S^1,\mathbb{R}^{2n}) $$

Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That space consists of functions $\mathbf{f}(\theta)$ defined on the unit circle with values in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ such that
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \|\mathbf{f}(\theta)\|^p \, d\theta < \infty.$$
Here $\| \cdot \|$ probably (if nothing else has been said) is the ordinary norm om $\mathbb{R}^{2n},$ i.e.
$$\| \mathbf{u} \| = \sqrt{ u_1^2 + \cdots + u_{2n}^2 }.$$

Comment: thanks for your comment, but should we also assume that the functions are measurable ?

Comment: We certainly should. Otherwise the integral is not defined.

Comment: okay, thank you for your comment. I am feeling quite unsure about the meaning of "measurable". May I ask you why this condition is important ? how do you understand it. Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: It has to do with the Lebesgue definition of integration. In your case, when we take an interval $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ then we need to be able to assign a total angle to the set $\{ \theta \in [0,2\pi) : \|\mathbf{f}(\theta)\|^p \in I \},$ and this requirement is more or less the definition of measurable function.

Comment: Okay, I will have a look at it, thanks for your help. May I ask you a last question ? Is it true that $L^p(S^1,\mathbb{R}^{2n})=L^p(S^1,\mathbb{C}^n)$ ? I just want to use the complex exponential to define an orthonormal basis. I mean I want to use the $e_n=e^{2 \pi i nx}$ but this isn't a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ so I thought about considering the matrix 
  $ J=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & \mathbb{I} \\
  - \mathbb{I} & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right],
$ instead of the imaginary unit $i$. Is this reasoning correct ?

Comment: I wouldn't say that $L^p(S^1,\mathbb{R}^{2n})$ and $L^p(S^1,\mathbb{C}^n)$ are the same sets, but they are isomorphic. The latter one has some more structure since you can multiply complex numbers in a way that isn't defined for plain $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I think that you can do something like $e_k = e^{2\pi i k x}$ but remember that you have $n$ complex dimensions, so you will need to take $k \in \mathbb{Z}^n$.

Comment: oh yes I see, yes of course the equal sign doesn't really make sense here. You're right, I should consider the basis $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ where $e_n = e^{2 pi n x J}$ I guess. Do you maybe have any recommendations for a book about measure theory ? I just finished my first year and I try to learn at home by myself. Again, thank you for your comments, it really helped a lot

Comment: In the course that I attended we used Folland's [Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications](https://www.amazon.com/Real-Analysis-Modern-Techniques-Applications/dp/0471317160). It's not cheap though, and my book (an older edition) partly falls apart. I think that you could find some good PDFs: https://www.google.com/search?q=measure+theory+pdf